# Unity 2019 - Android build fail

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I need to upgrade the version of my app that currently it is on the Google Play Store. This version was created in Unity 2018. Now I have upgraded my Unity to the 2019 version. I have done all the steps in order to upgrade my app (in fact I was able to generate a new version for the Itunes store) but every time I tried to generate the Android build I receive an error message. It seems that it is able to compile and do all the steps but then fails at the moment that it will save the package. (please see the error message on section 4)
I suspect that i have some missing configuration, but had checked all and all looks ok.

I have tried some "basic solutions":

1. change the folder where the build would be saved
2. try with gradle template (and without)
3. re import all assets

nothing works

This is the error message:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: You'll have to go look in your editor.log file for more details about the errors.

Comment: did you resolve it?